# sense of purpose in life vs purpose in life

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

What is the difference between "sense of purpose in life" vs "purpose in life".

**A person with few responsibilities might lose his sense of purpose in life.**

I was told that omitting "sense of" is wrong. However, when I translated it to my native language, I was not able to see any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, there often isn't much difference between the two. However, when there is, it's a matter of subjectivity versus objectivity.

In that respect, you can look at the two in the following way.

> I have a purpose.

This means that I actually *do* have a purpose. Other people can look at me and see that I'm doing something for a reason. Even if I don't see it myself, others do.

> I have a *sense of* purpose.

This means that *I* believe I'm doing something for a reason. It may be something that nobody else sees or cares about (and *they* might say I have no purpose), but *I* believe I'm doing something meaningful.

---

There is also a different shade of meaning between the two—one of enthusiasm.

Let's say you're captured by cannibals and, over a course of days, are slowly eaten. There can be no doubt that your purpose at that point is to feed the larger group.

If you are depressed by this turn of events, you might say:

> My only purpose now is to be a food source.

On the other hand, if you had been depressed about life before this happened, and didn't think you were doing anything worthwhile with yourself, and are actually *happy* about what has transpired, you could say with enthusiasm:

> I finally have a sense of purpose again—to feed these worthy people!

In the *sense of* version here, it's expressing a positive attitude rather than just a statement of fact.

---

In your own sentence, I personally find *sense of* to carry more meaning and be more appropriate to what I'm assuming it's trying to express. (Although I could be wrong.) As I read it, it's describing somebody without much to do and, therefore, *feeling* as if they aren't contributing. They may know that their actual purpose for working is to put food on the table, but they no longer have a *sense of* purpose. (The work itself seems monotonous and uninspiring.)

So, while it may not be wrong to omit *sense of*, it seems more likely that it should remain.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. I don't think that I will forget this example, and I will probably dream about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sense of purpose would mean a belief that one is born for a reason in life. Purpose in life is what one is born to do.

Comment: I don’t think ‘having a sense of purpose’ necessarily implies believing that you were *born* to do it.